# rstudio not working

Tags: 14.04, installed-programs

I have installed latest version of rstudio on my computer. When I try to run RStudio nothing starts. So I tried to open it from terminal and the following error comes

```
QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
"Invalid splitter position detected: -3/0" 
"Invalid splitter position detected: -5/0" 
"Invalid splitter position detected: -3/0" 
"Invalid splitter position detected: -5/0" 
"Invalid splitter position detected: -3/0" 
"Invalid splitter position detected: -5/0"
```

and it continues showing this, what might be the problem ? How to run RStudio properly ?

PS: I am having Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit version

Comment: Could you give details like your GTK+ Installation, Theme, and any custom changes?

Comment: I don't know about gtk ? If you can tell me how to check that , I can do that !

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126141/how-do-you-find-out-which-version-of-gtk-is-installed-on-ubuntu and try to determine details about your GTK, I'd also try reinstalling RStudio.

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple solution to my problem.

I did

```
rm ~/.config/RStudio/desktop.ini
```

after which I opened it again and it started to work.

Comment: Well that's a weird fix, maybe recreating the launcher did the trick.... glad you found such a simple fix.

Comment: This also works for Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands worked for me:

```
┌─[ricardoramos]@[falcon]:~
└──> $ sudo mkdir .rstudio-deskop
[sudo] password for ricardoramos: 
┌─[ricardoramos]@[falcon]:~
└──> $ sudo chown -R ricardoramos ~/.rstudio-desktop
```